# Django 1.11 Form to create multiple instances of model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am using Django 1.11 for my first Django/Python project and have been stuck for a few days trying to understand Formsets in order to create a form that will allow the creation of multiple model instances through one form. Any assistance that could be provided to help me understand and pass this issue will be greatly appreciated!

The way I have been approaching it is as follows:

I have the following model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    client_name = models.ForeignKey(Client,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True,default=datetime.now)
    assigned = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

I have the following form based on the model:

```
class FNTaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        exclude = ()
```

I have created the folllowing FormSet based on the above model & form:

```
TaskFormSet = modelformset_factory(Task, form = FNTaskForm, exclude=(),extra=2)
```

In views.py I have:

```
class FNTaskCreate(CreateView):
    model = Task
    form_class = FNTaskForm
    template_name = 'fntasks.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(FNTaskCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['formset'] = TaskFormSet(queryset=Task.objects.none()) # providing none
            return context
```

And finally I render it in my html template as:

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<table class="table link-formset">
{% for form in formset %}
{% if forloop.first %}
<thead>
  <tr>
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <th>{{ field.label }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</thead>
{% endif %}
<tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %} formset_row">
  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
  <td>
    {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
    {% if forloop.first %}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
    {{ field }}
  </td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'clients' %}">Cancel</a>
<input type="submit" value="Next" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

The form appears as follows on the page:
[image]

The issue I am having and that which I am gratefully seeking on help on resolving has 2 parts:

Part 1. I cannot successfully save data into the model using this form. I am not getting any errors however I believe that the form has 3 instances, not just the 2 instances displayed and it is a third (not visible instance) that is blank and hence not allowing the form to be valid. The reason I believe this is related to issue 2 (below). When I insert print my kwargs.pop variable to test it I get 3 outputs of 'None'. So I think in my ignorance and inexperience with Django I have not used the model formset factory correctly.

Part 2. I would also like to use kwargs to set the initial value of the 'Client Name' field using the kwarg 'clientlist' passed in the URL. I have used the following to confirm  the kwarg but the result is (None None None):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    clientlist = kwargs.pop('clientlist', None)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    print(clientlist)
```

The URL is as follows for passing the kwarg:

```
url(r'^tasks/create/(?P<clientlist>\d+)/$',views.FNTaskCreate.as_view(),name='fntask_create'),
```

Is anyone able to help me pass these issues to use modelformset_factory (or any other method that is better recommended) to successfuly save multiple model instances with one form with kwargs passed into the initial fields on the form? Thanking you for your time!